# type abstract method to return constructor props

Tags: typescript, class, oop

I need to implement an abstract class in typescript— let's call it `Entity`— with an abstract method— let's call it `constructorProps()`— which returns the array of props needed to construct the extending class.

For example, if `Foo extends Entity` but `Foo` has no constructor, the return type of `constructorProps()` should be an empty tuple:

```js
class Entity<Child extends Entity<any>> {
  abstract constructorProps(): // ??? what goes here ???
}


class Foo extends Entity<Foo> {
  override constructorProps() {
    return []
  }
}
```

on the other hand, say `Bar extends Entity` and it implements a constructor that takes one argument. Then `constructorProps()` should always return a `[string]`:

```js
class Bar extends Entity<Bar> {
  name: string;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  override constructorProps() {
    return [this.name];
  }
}
```

I think first clue is there— one can pass the extending class as a type parameter, so the abstract class can reference it. I don't know how to achieve what I need though.

- Is there a way to get the type of the constructor (arguments included) from an instance type (say, `ConstructorOf<Bar>`)?
- Am I approaching this correctly? Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the type of the constructor (arguments included) from an instance type (say, `ConstructorOf<Bar>`)?

No. An instance type does not have a link to it's constructor. So you need the type of the constructor itself, which you can get with `typeof MyClass`

---

It sounds like you want this:

```
type Constructable = { new (...args: never[]): unknown }

abstract class Entity<T extends Constructable> {
  abstract constructorProps(): Readonly<ConstructorParameters<T>>
}
```

Here `T` is the constructor of the child class. You can then use the `ConstructorParameters<T>` utility type to get the parameters for the constructor.

`type Constructable = { new (...args: never[]): unknown }` looks a little funky but it's just a generic constructor.

Note, that I added a `Readonly<T>` here because function arguments should always be a tuple that never should have it's length changed, and it plays nice with `as const` which we will need to use in the return value of `constructorProps()` to ensure it's a tuple and not an array.

---

Now the child class looks like this:

```
class Baz extends Entity<typeof Baz> {
  constructor(public a: number, public b: boolean) {
    super()
  }
  
  constructorProps() {
    return [this.a, this.b] as const; // as const infers this as a tuple
  }
}
```

Which works like you expect:

```
const baz = new Baz(123, true)
new Baz(...baz.constructorProps()) // works
```

And you do this wrong, you get the correct type error:

```
class Wrong extends Entity<typeof Wrong> {
  constructor(public a: number, public b: boolean) {
    super()
  }
  
  constructorProps() { // type error
    return ['a string'] as const;
  }
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=5.2.2#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-MtQoBKXIUAlUANtlQCVQsyCYOAEKhAHIcFB1KZ1emMXo5ig8UFlAogA)

Comment: Gotcha, and for things where I do need the instance type, I guess I can just use InstanceType<T>. Thanks!